# TYPO3 FAL images for translation don't work with tx_news (language)

Tags: typo3, translation, extbase, tx-news, fal

I am working with `TYPO3 CMS 6.2.14` and `tx_news (news georg ringer) 3.1.0`. My Website has two languages, german (L=0) and english (L=1).

Now I tried to translate a tx_news data record by clicking the british flag, so I'll have a 1:1-copy of the data record. Everything is fine. I can translate my text content - great!
[image: tx news records german english]

But what's about my images? My english data record only showing the german picture! I can upload new 'english images', but they won't be shown in Frontend. Only the german picture from the news data record.

This must be a massive problem in TYPO3 or tx_news? I don't know?
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57021

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272

But there's no solution for me at all. How can I use different FAL images or videos in two different data records from `tx_news`?

This is my `TypoScript`-Setup:

```
...
### not in use ## sys_language_mode = content_fallback
sys_language_overlay = 1
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the core bug is still there (TYPO3 7.6 & 8.7).
You can use the extension `repair_translation` to fix the translation handling with FAL objects.

Ext.https://github.com/froemken/repair_translation

Docs https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/repair_translation/Introduction/Index.html#the-typo3-bug

Comment: The extension I was looking for, thanks for sharing! 

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in core reportded on forge, see https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272

Comment: thanks for your answer .. issue is from 03/2014 .. hope they'll fix it at TYPO3 7.x